# Cannot play a mp3 file from a url with htts protocol in android

Tags: android, https, media-player

I am play a mp3 file from url containing a https protocol extention , I get a mediaplayer failed to prepare exception but when i use a http protocol the code runs fine

/****

```
                            import com.erkutaras.media.audio.url.R;

                            import android.app.Activity;
                            import android.media.MediaPlayer;
                            import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
                            import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
                            import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
                            import android.os.Bundle;
                            import android.os.Handler;
                            import android.util.Log;
                            import android.view.MotionEvent;
                            import android.view.View;
                            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                            import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
                            import android.widget.Button;
                            import android.widget.SeekBar;

                            public class StreamAudioFromUrlSampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
                                private Button btn_play,
                                btn_pause,
                                btn_stop;
                            private SeekBar seekBar;
                            private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
                            private int lengthOfAudio;
                            //  private final String URL = "http://android.erkutaras.com/media/audio.mp3";
                            private final String URL = "https://icanbeanything.com/en/Fearless/afraid-of-change.mp3";
                                private final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            private final Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            updateSeekProgress();   
                            }
                            };
                            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                                @Override
                                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                                    init();
                                }

                            private void init() {
                            btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
                            btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
                            btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
                            btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
                            btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
                            btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
                            btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);
                            btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
                            seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                            seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
                            seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            btn_play.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
                            btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            SeekBar tmpSeekBar = (SeekBar)v;
                            mediaPlayer.seekTo((lengthOfAudio / 100) * tmpSeekBar.getProgress() );
                            }
                            return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                            try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            lengthOfAudio = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            }
                            switch (view.getId()) {
                            case R.id.btn_play:
                            playAudio();
                            break;
                            case R.id.btn_pause:
                            pauseAudio();
                            break;
                            case R.id.btn_stop:
                            stopAudio();
                            break;
                            default:
                            break;
                            }
                            updateSeekProgress();
                            }

                            private void updateSeekProgress() {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
                            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                            }
                            }

                            private void stopAudio() {
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            btn_play.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
                            btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
                            seekBar.setProgress(0);
                            }

                            private void pauseAudio() {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            btn_play.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            private void playAudio() {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            btn_play.setEnabled(false);
                            btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
                            }


                            }

                                                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

*****/

Comment: Could you edit your code and fix identation? Horrible to read like this.

Comment: Developing in any version?

Answer (score 1):

If you developing on before Android 3.1

> HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1.

See this link

[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#network)